# Modify the registration in Community Builder + joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla-community-builder

I am working with the community builder package(CB) and joomla 3.3.1.
I want to modify the CB registration for adding a new input.
I want to add "phone" and put this number into the table for joomla users.

Any idea?

In advance, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should check [Community Builder Profile Pro plugin](http://www.joomduck.com/extensions/community-builder-profile-pro). It allows to place your custom HTML or even PHP code on CB registration page. You can add your custom input to the form and then process it on form submit by adding a trigger call using CB API. More info on CB Triggers http://www.joomlapolis.com/support/tutorials/120-api-usage/18358-using-cb-triggers